# How to get the count using javascript for below html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

i am trying to get the count of list items in an unordered list which is in dir-pagination-controls.how to get the count of list items using javascript?

```
<dir-pagination-controls min-size="1" direction-links="true" boundary-links="true" class="pull-right ng-isolate-scope"
                         pagination-id="openRabPagination"><!-- ngIf: 1 < pages.length -->
  <ul class="pagination ng-scope" ng-if="1 < pages.length"><!-- ngIf: boundaryLinks -->
    <li ng-if="boundaryLinks" ng-class="{ disabled : pagination.current == 1 }" class="ng-scope disabled"><a href=""
                                                                                                             ng-click="setCurrent(1)">«</a>
    </li><!-- end ngIf: boundaryLinks --><!-- ngIf: directionLinks -->
    <li ng-if="directionLinks" ng-class="{ disabled : pagination.current == 1 }" class="ng-scope disabled"><a href=""
                                                                                                              ng-click="setCurrent(pagination.current - 1)">‹</a>
    </li><!-- end ngIf: directionLinks --><!-- ngRepeat: pageNumber in pages track by $index -->
    <li ng-repeat="pageNumber in pages track by $index"
        ng-class="{ active : pagination.current == pageNumber, disabled : pageNumber == '...' }"
        class="ng-scope active"><a href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pageNumber)" class="ng-binding">1</a></li>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: pageNumber in pages track by $index -->
    <li ng-repeat="pageNumber in pages track by $index"
        ng-class="{ active : pagination.current == pageNumber, disabled : pageNumber == '...' }" class="ng-scope"><a
      href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pageNumber)" class="ng-binding">2</a></li>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: pageNumber in pages track by $index -->
    <li ng-repeat="pageNumber in pages track by $index"
        ng-class="{ active : pagination.current == pageNumber, disabled : pageNumber == '...' }" class="ng-scope"><a
      href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pageNumber)" class="ng-binding">3</a></li>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: pageNumber in pages track by $index -->
    <li ng-repeat="pageNumber in pages track by $index"
        ng-class="{ active : pagination.current == pageNumber, disabled : pageNumber == '...' }" class="ng-scope"><a
      href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pageNumber)" class="ng-binding">4</a></li>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: pageNumber in pages track by $index --><!-- ngIf: directionLinks -->
    <li ng-if="directionLinks" ng-class="{ disabled : pagination.current == pagination.last }" class="ng-scope"><a
      href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pagination.current + 1)">›</a></li><!-- end ngIf: directionLinks -->
    <!-- ngIf: boundaryLinks -->
    <li ng-if="boundaryLinks" ng-class="{ disabled : pagination.current == pagination.last }" class="ng-scope"><a
      href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pagination.last)">»</a></li><!-- end ngIf: boundaryLinks --></ul>
  <!-- end ngIf: 1 < pages.length -->
</dir-pagination-controls>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As tagged [jquery]

```
$("ul.pagination>li").length
```

```js
console.log($("ul.pagination>li").length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dir-pagination-controls min-size="1" direction-links="true" boundary-links="true" class="pull-right ng-isolate-scope"
                         pagination-id="openRabPagination"><!-- ngIf: 1 < pages.length -->
  <ul class="pagination ng-scope" ng-if="1 < pages.length"><!-- ngIf: boundaryLinks -->
    <li ng-if="boundaryLinks" ng-class="{ disabled : pagination.current == 1 }" class="ng-scope disabled"><a href=""
                                                                                                             ng-click="setCurrent(1)">«</a>
    </li><!-- end ngIf: boundaryLinks --><!-- ngIf: directionLinks -->
    <li ng-if="directionLinks" ng-class="{ disabled : pagination.current == 1 }" class="ng-scope disabled"><a href=""
                                                                                                              ng-click="setCurrent(pagination.current - 1)">‹</a>
    </li><!-- end ngIf: directionLinks --><!-- ngRepeat: pageNumber in pages track by $index -->
    <li ng-repeat="pageNumber in pages track by $index"
        ng-class="{ active : pagination.current == pageNumber, disabled : pageNumber == '...' }"
        class="ng-scope active"><a href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pageNumber)" class="ng-binding">1</a></li>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: pageNumber in pages track by $index -->
    <li ng-repeat="pageNumber in pages track by $index"
        ng-class="{ active : pagination.current == pageNumber, disabled : pageNumber == '...' }" class="ng-scope"><a
      href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pageNumber)" class="ng-binding">2</a></li>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: pageNumber in pages track by $index -->
    <li ng-repeat="pageNumber in pages track by $index"
        ng-class="{ active : pagination.current == pageNumber, disabled : pageNumber == '...' }" class="ng-scope"><a
      href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pageNumber)" class="ng-binding">3</a></li>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: pageNumber in pages track by $index -->
    <li ng-repeat="pageNumber in pages track by $index"
        ng-class="{ active : pagination.current == pageNumber, disabled : pageNumber == '...' }" class="ng-scope"><a
      href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pageNumber)" class="ng-binding">4</a></li>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: pageNumber in pages track by $index --><!-- ngIf: directionLinks -->
    <li ng-if="directionLinks" ng-class="{ disabled : pagination.current == pagination.last }" class="ng-scope"><a
      href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pagination.current + 1)">›</a></li><!-- end ngIf: directionLinks -->
    <!-- ngIf: boundaryLinks -->
    <li ng-if="boundaryLinks" ng-class="{ disabled : pagination.current == pagination.last }" class="ng-scope"><a
      href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pagination.last)">»</a></li><!-- end ngIf: boundaryLinks --></ul>
  <!-- end ngIf: 1 < pages.length -->
</dir-pagination-controls>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using vanilla javascript you could use `querySelectorAll` which returns a NodeList which you could then get the [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/length) of. For your case a selector like `ul.pagination>li` should work

Answer (score 0):

You can do something as simple as:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("pagination ng-scope")[0].childElementCount
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript all html elements have a `childElementsCount` property.
If you only have `li` tags in the `ul` tag, you can simply use this line of code:
    `let listElements = document.querySelector("ul").childElementsCount;`

If you have other tags in the `ul` tag you have to get all children and loop through them. If the name of the child is `li` you can add 1 to the count.